pivottablejs give the error " 'pivot_ui' from partially initialized"
I'm attempting to utilize the pivottablejs library, but it's not importing correctly, resulting in an error. Please take a look at my code and the error message.
My code:
import pandas as pd
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
from IPython.display import HTML
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:/mainfol/book1.csv")
pivot_ui(df, outfile_path=r"c:/mainfol/testpivot.html")

Error:
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
ImportError: cannot import name 'pivot_ui' from partially initialized module 'pivottablejs' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\mainfolder\pivottablejs.py)

Please give me an idea how can I use the pivottablejs in Python?

most likely due to a circular import

error
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
ImportError: cannot import name 'pivot_ui' from partially initialized module 'pivottablejs' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\mainfolder\pivottablejs.py)

You have named your own script pivottablejs.py.  THAT is being found by the import, rather than the actual intended module.

sir please send me the sample code i am new in python

ok sir ok you are right and good very good master my code run without any error thank you
